# How to do vertical infinite repeating background for a JavaScript game?

Tags: javascript

I have been looking at the code of this Flappy Bird clone to figure out how to repeat a background image vertically but have had no luck so far. 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/778727/Build-Flappy-Bird-with-jQuery-and-lines-of-Javascr

I've altered the code so far to be able to scroll down, but the repetition of the bg image stops after around 800pixels of moving down and for the hell of me I cant figure out why!

I have heard that this code is not the best code out there, so if someone has another way to do this I'm all ears.

This is the codepen to preview the nonworking background:
http://codepen.io/tangwei/pen/dpbQPZ

```
var bird = null, board = null;
var dimPipe = { width:40, height:420 }, cPos = { x: 80, y:100, h:40, w:50 };
var gravity = 0.5, iniSpeed = -7, curSpeed = 0;
var score = 0, noClr = 0, tmStep = 0, state = 0;        // 0-not started,1-play,2-over;

(function($) {
    $.cssNumber.rotate = true;
    $.cssHooks.rotate = {
        set : function(el, v) {
            if (typeof v === 'string')
                v = (v.indexOf("rad") != -1) ? parseInt(v) * 180 / Math.PI : parseInt(v);
            v = (~~v);
            if (v == ($.data(el, 'rotate') || 0)) return;
            el.style["MozTransform"] = el.style["MozTransform"] = el.style["-webkit-transform"]
                = el.style["transform"] = " rotate(" + (v % 360) + "deg)";
            $.data(el, 'rotate', v);
        },
        get : function(el, computed) {
            return $.data(el, 'rotate') || 0;
        }
    };
})(jQuery);

function gameOver() {
    state = 2;
    $(":animated").stop();
    if (tmStep) tmStep = window.clearInterval(tmStep);
    bird.animate({ top:board.height()-cPos.h, rotate:540}, 1000)
        .animate({ top:board.height()-cPos.h}, 500, function() {
            $('#score').text(' Score: ' + score);
            start();
        });
}
function Parallax(elm, tmo) {
    elm.animate({top:-1000}, { // play around with this value to determine speed
            duration:tmo*50, easing:'linear', //step : PrlxStep,
            complete : function() { Parallax(elm, tmo); }
    });
}

function BirdStep() {
    curSpeed += gravity;
    cPos.y = Math.max(cPos.y + curSpeed, 0);
    var ang = curSpeed * 5, mh = board.height()-cPos.h, m = -12, lo = 0, actPipe = $('.obs');
    bird.css({top: cPos.y, rotate:(ang < -20) ? -20 : (ang > 90) ? 90 : ang});
    // if (cPos.y > mh)
    //  return gameOver();
    // for (var i = actPipe.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    //  var s = actPipe[i].style, x = parseInt(s.left), y = parseInt(s.top);
    //  lo = Math.max(lo, x);
    //  if (x+dimPipe.width +m < cPos.x || x > cPos.x+cPos.w+m) continue;
    //  if (y+dimPipe.height+m < cPos.y || y > cPos.y+cPos.h+m) continue;
    //  return gameOver();
    // }
    // if (actPipe.length > 3 || lo > 300 || Math.random() >= 0.05 * (1+noClr))
    //  return;
    // var og = cPos.h * 2;
    // var oh = og + Math.floor(Math.random() * (mh-og+1));
    // var obs = $("<img/><img/>").addClass('c obs').css({left:480, zIndex:3}).css(dimPipe).attr('src', 'vine.png')
    //  .appendTo(board).animate({left:-50}, Math.max(2000,3500-noClr*50), 'linear', function() {
    //      $('#score').text(' Score: ' + (score += 1 + Math.floor(++noClr/10)));
    //      this.remove();
    //  });
    // obs[0].style.top = oh + 'px';
    // obs[1].style.top = (oh - og - dimPipe.height) + "px";
}
function onTap() {
    if (state > 1) return;
    if (state == 0) {
        state = 1;
        $('#score').text(' Score: ' + (score = 0));
        Parallax($('#bGrnd'), 40);
        Parallax($('#fGrnd'), 80);
        $('#instr').hide();
        tmStep = window.setInterval(BirdStep, 30);
    }
    curSpeed = iniSpeed;
}
function start() {
    state = noClr = score = 0;                  // not started
    cPos = { x: 80, y:100, h:40, w:50 };
    bird.css({left:cPos.x, top:cPos.y, width:cPos.w, height:cPos.h, rotate:0});
    // $('.obs').remove();
    $('#instr').show();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    bird = $('#bird');
    var evt = (typeof(bird[0].ontouchend) == "function") ? "touchstart" : "mousedown";
    board = $('#board').bind(evt, onTap);
    start();


    setInterval(function(){
        var bGrnd = $("#bGrnd");
        var curr_height = parseInt(bGrnd.css("height"));
        curr_height += 1000;
        bGrnd.css("height", curr_height);
    },2000)
});
```